# Create array with checked boxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox, destructuring

i want to create a combination game checkin some elements with checkboxes

i need to create a array while the user check a checkbox and compare with the correct array

i dont know who do that

this is my inputs

```
<section class="draggable-items">
    <div class="check-tool">
        <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox-tool" name="tool" id="SBD710" value="SBD710">
        <img class="draggable correct" draggable="true" src="img-game/WOOD/SBD710.png">
    </div>
    <div class="check-tool">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-tool" name="tool"  id="SCS220" value="SCS220">
        <img class="draggable correct" draggable="true" src="img-game/WOOD/SCS220.png">
    </div>
    <div class="check-tool">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-tool" name="tool"  id="SB201" value="SB201">
        <img  class="draggable correct" draggable="true" src="img-game/WOOD/SB201.png">
    </div>
    <div class="check-tool">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-tool" name="tool"  id="SB204" value="SB204">
        <img class="draggable correct" draggable="true" src="img-game/WOOD/SB204.png">
    </div>
    <div class="check-tool">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-tool" name="tool"  id=SBG700" value="SBG700">
        <img  class="draggable correct" draggable="true" src="img-game/WOOD/SBG700.png">
    </div>


</section>
    <button id="check" class="btn">Construye</button>
```

if somebody can explain me how to create that array with push method and who make the
comparison with the correct combination array

Comment: Do you want to make an array of checked items or checked values, like [1, 0, 1] or [SBG700, null, null...]?

Comment: checked items like [1, 0, 1]

Comment: Do you use jquery or javascript only?

Comment: You haven't really explained what that array is meant to do, and what values you're meant to be checking against? [Here's some documentation on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the demo for your solution

```js
   

 let check = function () {
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
           result.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        } else {
           result.push('null');
        }
  }

  console.log(result);
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="SBG701" onChange="check()" />
<input type="checkbox" value="SBG702" onChange="check()" />
<input type="checkbox" value="SBG703" onChange="check()" />
<input type="checkbox" value="SBG704" onChange="check()" />
```

Comment: what i need to change if a want the array look like this  [SBG700, null, null...]

Comment: If my correct combinantion is this array let correctAnswer = ['SBD710', 'SCS220', 'SB201', 'SB204', null, 'SB202', 'SBC550', 'SCJ600', 'SC200', null] i can make the comparation is result == correctAnswer. i am just a beginner on this

Comment: `JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(correctAnswer);` will work for most situations @SantiagoDiaz